# Anaconda not working with atom terminal for python

Tags: python, anaconda, atom-editor

I tried installing Anaconda in my windows 10 but for using with atom editor. But it only works with anaconda prompt and not with terminal of atom for python

Comment: You can try to following tutorial: https://pythonhow.com/using-atom-as-a-python-editor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all have you set the **anaconda python path in the system variable**
 cause atom wont be able to find the anaconda version of python and will get default python or will break.

Then to check whether Anaconda is installed properly try opening **Anaconda Navigator** if no then re install.

Further it is **not dependent on Atom** in any ways possible as it is simply an editor.

Verify your system settings and then try again.Also see to it that the path must contain the anaconda version of python and not other version.

After adding it to the path you will be able to use it from anywhere on your system.